# Call to a member function update() on integer - Laravel

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, sql-update

I call the update function in my controller so I can apply the changes to advert from the edit form template. I get the following error.

> Call to a member function update() on integer

This is my update controller code

```
public function update(Request $request, $id){
      PropertyAdvert::where('id', $id)->where('user_id', Auth::id()->update
      ([
        "photo"       => base64_encode(file_get_contents($request->photo->path())),
        "address"     => $request->address,
        "county"      => $request->county,
        "town"        => $request->town,
        "type"        => $request->type,
        "rent"        => $request->rent,
        "date"        => $request->date,
        "bedrooms"    => $request->bedrooms,
        "bathrooms"   => $request->bathrooms,
        "furnished"   => $request->furnished,
        "description" => $request->description,
        "user_id" => Auth::id(),
      ]));

      return back();
    }
```

My edit form is quite big so I don't think I should post this.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's a typo. You're calling `->update` on `Auth::id()`, not the query. Move the last bracket the bracket before `;` to end the `->where(..)` part.

Here, this should work:

```
PropertyAdvert::where('id', $id)->where('user_id', Auth::id())->update([
    "photo"       => base64_encode(file_get_contents($request->photo->path())),
    "address"     => $request->address,
    "county"      => $request->county,
    "town"        => $request->town,
    "type"        => $request->type,
    "rent"        => $request->rent,
    "date"        => $request->date,
    "bedrooms"    => $request->bedrooms,
    "bathrooms"   => $request->bathrooms,
    "furnished"   => $request->furnished,
    "description" => $request->description,
    "user_id" => Auth::id(),
]);
```

Comment: This is where a decent IDE is useful. That would have flagged that up instantly.